Parity transformation of the $\pi^{0}\rightarrow\gamma\gamma$ process
I want to prove that the amplitude
$$\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}=\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}q_{1\alpha}q_{2\beta}$$
is violating parity. Here $q_{i=1,2}$ are the external momenta of the photons. The total amplitude will be then $\sim\epsilon_{\mu}^{1}\epsilon_{\nu}^{2}\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}$.
As far as I know, the Levi-Civita tensor transforms with a minus sign but the product of the momenta does change sign depending on whether we choose their mixed components or both spatial/temporal ones, so I don't get $\mathcal{M}^{'\mu\nu}=-\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}$. What am I missing? Is it possible that under parity I have to switch $1\leftrightarrow2$ so that the minus sign comes just from the Levi civita transformation?

In my notes I have written that this amplitude can be associated to the above process because of the fact that $\pi^{0}$ is a pseudo scalar, so it should be chosen instead of $\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}\sim q_{1}^{\mu}q_{2}^{\nu}$ because of parity violating arguments. I am trying to convince about it instead of doing the full loop calculation. As a reference, see Schwartz chapter 30

(30.1) &  (30.2) preserve parity.

Ok, but if I want to see it directly from the amplitude, how do I apply P? The momenta should swamp sign in the spatial components, the Levi-Civita should change sign but then I don't get an overall minus sign... To be honest I am not really sure that this procedure makes sense so I would like some hints


... how do I apply P?

Spacelike components of a vector/tensor reverse their components. But the Levi-Civita  symbol is a pseudotensor, so its three space like reversals amount to changing the coordinate system from a right-handed to a left-handed one, so $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$ flips.
Consequently
$$
{\cal M}  \propto \epsilon ^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} \epsilon^{1*}_\mu \epsilon^{2*}_\nu q_{1\alpha}q_{2\beta} \tag{3.10}
$$
is odd under parity, for the same reason $\tilde F \cdot F$ is.
It should be obvious to you that 1↔2
does not reverse any signs, as it virtually interchanges pairs of indices.
So their product with the neutral pion, a pseudoscalar, is parity invariant, as it should be for interactions involving strong and EM interactions only.

But why the term $\epsilon^{1}{\mu}\epsilon^{2}{\nu}q_{1\alpha}q_{2\beta}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}{\mu\rho}\mathcal{P}{\nu\sigma}\mathcal{P}{\alpha\lambda}\mathcal{P}{\beta\theta}\epsilon^{1\rho}\epsilon^{2\sigma}q_{1}^{\lambda}q_{2}^{\theta}$ doesn't change sign? The Levi civita force you to take one temporal and three spatial so you should get $(-1)^{3}$ no?

Look at the object without free indices,  (3.10). It has three spacelike reversals matched by three such, but it also flips the chirality of the coordinate system. You understand and accept the parity oddness of $\tilde F \cdot F$, right?

If you mean $F\cdot\widetilde{F}\sim \stackrel{\rightarrow}{E}\cdot \stackrel{\rightarrow}{B}$ yes. But I need to think about what you said, I have never thought much about those stuff.

I've thought about that, is it correct to say the following ? $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow}-\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$ while $V_{\mu}V_{\nu}V_{\alpha}V_{\beta}\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{P}{\mu\rho}\mathcal{P}{\nu\sigma}\mathcal{P}{\alpha\theta}\mathcal{P}{\beta\lambda}V^{\rho}V^{\sigma}V^{\theta}V^{\lambda} $ doesn't change sign cause $\mathcal{P}{00}\mathcal{P}{ii}\mathcal{P}{jj}\mathcal{P}{kk}=+1$, I have denoted with $\mathcal{P}^{\mu}{\nu}$ the parity matrix:$\mathcal{P}^{0}{0}=+1,\mathcal{P}^{i}{j}=-δ^{i}{j}$.

ε transforms like a tensor with an extra - sign, while your peculiar (fully symmetric) tensor, if all 4 indices are different, with an overall - sign, so the saturation of ε with it would be a pseudoscalar if it didn't vanish from symmetry. So, $\epsilon^{abcd}V_aW_bU_cX_d$ has negative parity...
